# I have an indoor swimming pool - can I have a large mirror, or will it be steamed all the time?

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures, condensation

I have a dehumidifier in my indoor swimming pool room, I would like a large dance mirror on the wall - would it be constantly covered in condensation.
My room humidity is controlled to 50%.

Just don’t want to add a huge wall mirror to find it a mess all the time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Heat it to just above the dew point, then water won’t be condensing on the surface.

Comment: what is preventing you from bringing a small mirror into the pool area?

Comment: @jsotola - presumably small mirror is to test for fog.

Comment: of course ... a small mirror will condense steam just as readily as a wall size mirror

Answer (score 4):

Are the walls wet? If not, then a mirror the same temperature as the wall it's mounted on will also not be wet, as the water is not condensing on the walls.

If the walls are too cold and the water is condensing on the them, then it will condense on a mirror mounted on them, since that will also be too cold.

Constant fogging is primarily a problem (in my experience) where a poorly insulated mostly-glass structure is built over an originally outdoor pool. If your pool room is inside a house that's properly insulated, that's far less likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

if the mirror is at room temperature it won't fog at less than 100% humidity.

This may require good insulation behind the mirror,